# Sorting a one-to-many join

Tags: mysql

Say I have two tables. **Albums** and **Pictures**. Records in the **Albums** table have a one-to-many relationship with records in the **Pictures** table.

I need to be able to get *x* amount of albums **and** the number of pictures associated with each album, so that I can sort by number of pictures.

What's the best way to do this? Can it be done with a single query or will I need to run several queries?

Comment: Do you just want the number of pictures per album? or do you want the actual pictures listed in each row as well?

Comment: It'd be nice to have the actual pictures as well as the number, but it looks like that would have to be done in separate queries..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use an aggregate function/group by clause to accomplish this eg:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(p.id)
FROM Albums a LEFT JOIN Pictures p on a.id = p.album_id
GROUP BY a.name
ORDER BY COUNT(p.id) DESC
LIMIT 10
```